# IONIC UPDATE ERROR 243 on mac

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, terminal

? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.19.0 => 3.19.1)! Would you like to in
stall it? Yes

> npm i -g ionic@latest
>   ✖ Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i -g ionic@latest (exit code 243):

Answer (score 0):

since mac having access issue this error will pop up.so what you have to do is run it as admin it will popup for administrator password.request update as below command in terminal

```
sudo npm i -g ionic@latest
```